# How to parse input type value of html and convert it into pdf?

Tags: java

I am unable to parse the html input type value and convert it into pdf file.I am using pdfWriter to generate the pdf and using xmlworker-5.5.4.jar and itext.jar.It does not parse the input type value of html file and unable to convert into pdf file.This problem is generating when using htmlworker or xmlworker.

```
Code:
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
public class ParseHtml {
    public static final String DEST = "D:/html_1.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        ParseHtml p=new ParseHtml();
        p.createPdf(DEST);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.append("<input type=\'text\' value=\"43645643634\"/>");
        System.out.println("String------"+sb);
        FileOutputStream outStream =  new FileOutputStream(file);
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,outStream);

        document.open();
        document.newPage();        
        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
        htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(sb.toString())); 



document.close();
        outStream.close();
        System.out.println("Document is created...");
    }
}
```